# How to verify background color and font color of a button using tosca

Tags: tosca

I am trying to automate background color and font color of a button in Tosca,but couldn't able to do it, could any one help me on this

Comment: provide your code snippet

Comment: You might want to check Tricentis Community [https://community.tricentis.com/] to get help on Tosca.

Answer (score 0):

You can use image based scan to verify the color of the background.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).